# SQL Server 2008: How do I change the default schema of the dbo?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, schema

When I attempt to change the default schema of the dbo in SQL Server Management Studio, the ALTER fails and states that the dbo account's schema cannot be changed. Are there any tricks that can make is possible to change the the dbo default schema of "dbo" to "xxx"?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @gbn, I have been playing around with this for the past 15 minutes and my below answer is the only conclusion I can come up with.  Even if I am executing as a separate `sysadmin` login with a separate `db_owner` user I still get denied.

Comment: @Surfer513: Did you mean to to address @user962143?

Comment: @gbn no, I did mean to address you. I wanted a sanity check on my theory. :)  My pursuit of what is fact, short of finding exact explanation in documentation, could be faulty and I was just looking to see if I had the right idea before I give some bad gouge.

Answer (score 7):

Each database is owned by a server principal (aka login).  Inside that database, the owning principal is known as `dbo` (aka **D**ata**B**ase **O**wner).  The database principal (aka user) loses its real name.

For example, for a database I own:

```
select  [user].name as UserName -- Database specific
,       [login].name as LoginName -- Server wide
from    sys.databases d
join    sys.database_principals as [user]
on      [user].sid = d.owner_sid
join    sys.server_principals as [login]
on      [login].sid = d.owner_sid
```

Will print "dbo", "Andomar".  If you'd change the owner to `sa`:

```
exec sp_changedbowner 'sa'
```

The query would return "dbo", "sa".

You cannot modify the default schema for the user that owns a database.  It is always user name `dbo` with default schema name `dbo`.

Answer (score 3):

Database User `dbo` is mapped to logins of the `sysadmin` fixed server role.  I believe it is because of this that you can't alter the default schema for db user `dbo`.

The real question is, *why do you want to change the default schema of `dbo` to something else?*  With built-in specifics (fixed roles, fixed logins/users), you really should be minimizing how must you customize them.

If you don't want users to have a default schema of `dbo`, then maybe you should reconsider your logins and database users so they don't map to max rights objects.

Comment: Yep, most built-in principals have limited options to change anything. And it is best practice to qualify all objects with schema anyway.

Comment: The owner of a database is not always `sa`.  A user can own a database without being a member of the `sysadmin` fixed server role